# How to implement good initial value and solution range using python scipy fsolve? [a simple example]

Tags: python, range, scipy-optimize

Here I want to solve a simple equation using fsolve. I know the solution exists for any positive value. However, it seems the success with fsolve depends on the initial value selection. My guess is that this could be due to the domain of the h has to be positive because of "log", and the fsolve process encountered negative trials.

Currently my attempted solution is to use `try:` with randomized initial value until there is a good solution.

My question:
It it possible to force fslove to search within a range, say (0,1)? I know scipy.optimize.brentq accepts solution range, but the range has to be opposite signs(+-), which is not my case.

Here is the code

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.optimize import fsolve

def h_f(h):
    # h range is (0,1)
    return -2/(np.log(h))

def find(h, r):
    return np.abs(r - h_f(h))   # to be minimized to zero

# find solution of h so h_f(h)=6
fsolve(find, x0=0.1, args=(6))[0] # bad initial value RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in log

fsolve(find, x0=0.7, args=(6))[0] # good initial value solution h=0.8464817248906141
```

Now try to use minimize with bounds: no luck, failed to find solution

```
from scipy.optimize import minimize
res = minimize(find, x0=0.1, args=(6), bounds=((1e-12,1-1e-12),))

      fun: array([5.56570552])
 hess_inv: <1x1 LbfgsInvHessProduct with dtype=float64>
      jac: array([-1.88611695])
  message: b'CONVERGENCE: REL_REDUCTION_OF_F_<=_FACTR*EPSMCH'
     nfev: 6
      nit: 1
   status: 0
  success: True
        x: array([0.1])
```

update with "less" extreme bounds:

```
res = minimize(find, x0=0.1, args=(6), bounds=((1e-3,1-1e-3),))
```

worked.

Comment: What about using scipy.optimize.minimize and setting the objective function to the absolute difference? It has 'bounds' argument. Note that your algorithm choice will be limited (check the docs)

Comment: @nichostst, I tried to use `minimize` with `bounds`, but still could not find the solution. I updated that part in the post.

Comment: `minimize` worked this setting `bounds=((1e-3,1-1e-3),)` which is less extreme as `bounds=((1e-12,1-1e-12),)`. Any idea why?